# Is it possible to get skyrim mods on xbox 360?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360, mods

I'm looking for a mod that will stack multiple smaller souls to fill a larger soul gem.  Is this possible on 360?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. There are no Xbox mods for Skyrim (and [there probably won't ever be either](https://web.archive.org/web/20111223034015/http://www.oxm.co.uk/30911/features/why-xbox-360-needs-skyrim-mods-but-will-never-get-them/)).

Comment: are there mods for any game on xbox?

Comment: Not in a legal and straightforward manner, no, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: There are halo 3 mods. I am sure it's possible to get skyrim mods on there.

Comment: Just to add to this accepted answer, because it says "Xbox mods" and not "Xbox 360 mods": The Xbox One version of Skyrim *does* support mods.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a modded 360 you can install mods. When you extract the files from the DVD the folder structure is the same as the PC version, and you can install mods the same way. Some mods don't work correctly, but most work pretty well. This may be illegal in most countries because you must bypass DRM/copy protection mechanisms in the xbox. It might be legal if you own the game (because you wouldn't have modded your xbox with the intent to pirate games), but I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's illegal, regardless.  The DMCA specifically prohibits anti-circumventiom measures, and modding is exactly that.  I'm afraid this isn't an answer we can condone, as we don't allow anything related to piracy.

Comment: @fbueckert Circumventing DRM is legal in jurisdictions that do not have the DMCA or equivalent, and the answer does pretty much say so. (Owning the disc, on the other hand, is irrelevant for this.)