# Does Skyrim on the 360 allow mods?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360, mods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to get skyrim mods on xbox 360?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45711/is-it-possible-to-get-skyrim-mods-on-xbox-360)

Are you allowed different mods activated at the same time, or can you only have one activated at a time.  Also, can you still have your old save game with the mod added?

Comment: I do not believe the 360 supports mods of ANY kind, due to it's closed marketplace.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid no third party mods of any kind are available to gamers playing Skyrim on the 360, or any other games console for that matter.